# How React Native and Android Native combine during build process to generate apk?

Tags: android, react-native

I started learning react native for Android and am trying to understand how the build process really works.

This what i have understood so far.

- React Native code and JS code runs of JRE(JavaScript Runtime Environment)
- Android Runs on Android OS (as usual)
- React Native code and Android Native code communicated through a channel, called **Bridge**.
- Node server publishes a bundle, which consists of all the react native codes.

Fair enough.

So, now when it comes to apk generation, how the dex files and res files and the bundle files are packed together to generate an apk.